# How can the top DIV from two stacking DIVs affect the other's height

Tags: html, css

As the title suggests, I have two stacking `<div>`s.

They are placed in an absolutely positioned container that covers the whole page. Basically, those 2 `<div>`s, taken together, should also cover the whole space of the containier.

Another important aspect is that these `<div>`s have dynamic content. The *bottom* one can have a lot of content, so an `overflow: auto` rule is required. The *top* one can also have dynamic content, but it's not really expected to grow out of control. Thus, I don't want to cut the overflow.

**The main question is:** How can the top one affect the other one's height without the risk of overlapping? (I prefer a ***CSS only*** solution, or something that wouldn't imply JS pixel values computations)

Here are two images that describe the best what I'm trying to achieve:

1. ["initial state"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZdxN.png)
2. [a state with some more data in the top div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsjGR.png)

Here is also a JSfiddle for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/60qan4t6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of situation that `display:flex` handles extremely well.  Update to your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/60qan4t6/1/

Note, I quickly wrote this, so it's missing browser prefixes to support some browsers, but the fiddle should work in Chrome just fine.

Be sure to see check browser support for flexbox here:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Seems like flexbox is the only CSS-only solution available from what I read as well. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to set height to div's you can use such an example

```
.top-area {
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40%;
}

.bottom-area {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 60%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xqh2vw2g/